# regex not working C#

Tags: c#, regex

i have a textbox in form. i want to write there in the textbox, the path (ex: D:\temp) and after that, i want to create this path.
I tried to use this regex but is not working! i want the first letter be upper but is not working. Also i want the string contain ":" and "\" just once. And after ":\" i want to insert some string lowercase
 @"^*[A-Z]*[:]*[\]*[a-z]$"
Have some sugestions ? 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Show what you have tried and isnt working.

Comment: [a-z] is only allowing one lower case character.  Add + after it to allow 1 or more or use * for zero or more.  And you need to delimit the backslash with a second one as it is currently delimiting the ].

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working"? What should work, what should fail? Give us examples!

Comment: `[\]` should probably be \\ as well

Comment: for example if i insert "a:\temp" this is correct... i want something like this "A:\temp"

Comment: Of course you confused quantifiers. Use `@"^[A-Z]:\\[a-z]*$"` (or if the number of lowercase letters should be at least 1: `@"^[A-Z]:\\[a-z]+$"`)

Comment: thank you Wiktor Stribiżew ... now I understand...

Answer (score 2):

I believe the regular expression you are looking for is

```
@"^[A-Z]:\\[a-z]+$"
```

There are two issues with your's.  First you didn't delimit the backslash, so it was delimiting the ] which meant you were looking for exactly one ], [, or a through z after the colon.  The second issue is that you want to find one or more letters after the backslash so you need to use + for that.  Finally the colon and backslash do not have to be in groups.

Comment: Based on the question, I also believe this is what is being asked for, but the OP should be aware that it won't match paths that have more than one nested directory. For example D:\temp\other will not match.

Comment: @fiveclubs It also won't match a file if it has an extension because it doesn't match the dot, and it won't match mixed case directory or file name or anything that has a non alpha character like underscore or a number.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try this:

```
[RegularExpression("^("[A-Z][a-z]+$)",
ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Correct Name")]
```

Description

- `^`  Beginning of string
- `[ ]`  Brackets specifies set of characters
- `A-Z a-z` All capital/small letters
- Consider a space
- `+` one or more letters
- `$` Indicates end of string

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex : [A-Z]:\[a-z]+.
Then try ^[A-Z]:\\w+$

Declare your regex like this in your code :

```
string myRegex = @"[A-Z]:\\[a-z]+"
```

With this, you only validate paths like D:\Temp, but not D:\Temp\Temp2

Answer (score 0):

First, examples of what should pass or fail would be helpful.

Second, use a tool to help write the regex that explains what's happening as you go, like Expresso or Regex Fiddle.

Now, on to the question. Here's an example `/^[A-Z]:\\[a-z]+$/gm`

- ^ - It matches the start of a line
- [A-Z] - matches a single capital letter
- : - matches a colon
- \ - escape the backslash to match a
  backslash
- [a-z]+ - matches a *lower*case letter (the + means 1 or
  more times)
- $ - match the end of line

Here's an edited version which checks to ensure first character of folder is a capital letter `/^[A-Z]:\\[A-Z][a-z]+$/gm`

Comment: if you want multiple folders like `D:\one\two` we need to make a change to this...also, are you sure you just want lower case foldernames?

Comment: yes .. lowercase ... but what if the folder names should have the first letter upper? What should I do?

Comment: Then you have to add that to the regex before the lowercase stuff, like this `/^[A-Z]:\\[A-Z][a-z]+$/gm` I added a single check for a capital letter before the lowercase check...currently this regex will pass `D:\Fo` but fail for `D:\F` because it requires a capital letter and 1 or more lowercase. Changing the `+` to a `*` would change it to 0 or more lowercase letters